# More optimal method to find arbitrarily prime gaps?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading  wolfram article about prime gaps(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) and i thought that the method for finding arbitrarily large prime gaps is improvable.
$$\text{If }p_i, p_2,p_3....p_k \text{are all the primes less than or equal  than n, then if}\\
 m=\prod_{k=1}^{k=n+1}p_k\\ 
\text{all numbers from m+2 to m+n will be composite}\\
$$
My question is more about why don't they include this as a prime-gap generating algorithm, because I think that more than one have thought about this, and that m will be much lower than (n+1)!, therefore generating much lower bounds.

Comment: "More optimal" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way they demonstrate the existence of arbitrarily long prime gaps on [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Simple_observations).

I would guess MathWorld uses $n!$ because it is slightly easier to understand and because both approaches give bounds that are very weak.